# How can I enable photo comments on my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-comments

It shows:

> Photo comments on this page are not allowed.

I want to allow visitors to comment on a post with photos (to upload a photo on the comment section) on my Facebook page.
How can I do it?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

You will click "settings" tab at the top right of the screen of the page. Ensure you have "general" tab selected on the left hand side. You will then look for "Visitor Posts" section. It should be the second from the top. You will click edit on the right. Then choose required option.

Comment: I don't find any "enabling photo commenting" option in the "Visitor Posts" section! Which option is required for my purpose there?
This is what I found: https://i.paste.pics/8DM2B.png

Comment: This allows users to publish posts on your page. OP said he wants to allow only posting images in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just click allow photos and videos

Comment: where would I click?
Write in details please.